# Updating MS Access Database through DataGridView in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I'm new to vb.net and I'm trying to update my MS access database from a datagridview in visual basic through a button. Whenever I click on the button to update, I'm getting an error which says "NullReferenceException was unhandled". Please help me. These are my codes:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Public Cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Public Cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Public DR As OleDbDataReader
    Public DA As OleDbDataAdapter
    Public DS As DataSet
    Public DT As DataTable
    Public cmdBld As OleDbCommandBuilder

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DTBClassRecordsDataSet.tblRecords' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TblRecordsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DTBClassRecordsDataSet.tblRecords)

        dgvRecords.AllowUserToAddRows = True
        dgvRecords.AutoGenerateColumns = True



        If Cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then Cnn.Close()
        Cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\JEM FLOR\Projects\CLASS RECORD\DTBClassRecords.accdb"
        Cnn.Open()

        Cmd.Connection = Cnn


        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        DA = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tblRecords", Cnn)
        Dim cb = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        cb.QuotePrefix = "["
        cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"
        da.Fill(dt)
        dgvRecords.DataSource = dt.DefaultView



        DataGridShow()

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridShow()
        Cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblRecords", Cnn)

        Cnn.Open()

        DA = New OleDbDataAdapter(Cmd)

        cmdBld = New OleDbCommandBuilder(DA)

        DS = New DataSet()

        DA.Fill(DS, "table1")

        dgvRecords.DataSource = DS.Tables("tblRecords").DefaultView

        Cnn.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub dgvRecords_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvRecords.CellEndEdit
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvRecords.Rows
            On Error Resume Next

            If Not row.IsNewRow Then

                row.Cells("QR1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value = ((row.Cells("Q1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value / row.Cells("TI1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value) * 50 + 50)
                row.Cells("QR2DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value = ((row.Cells("Q2DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value / row.Cells("TI2DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value) * 50 + 50)
                row.Cells("QR3DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value = ((row.Cells("Q3DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value / row.Cells("TI3DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value) * 50 + 50)
                row.Cells("QR4DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value = ((row.Cells("Q4DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value / row.Cells("TI4DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value) * 50 + 50)
                row.Cells("QR5DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value = ((row.Cells("Q5DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value / row.Cells("TI5DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value) * 50 + 50)
            End If

            Dim qr1 As Integer = row.Cells("QR1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value.ToString
            Dim qr2 As Integer = row.Cells("QR2DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value.ToString
            Dim qr3 As Integer = row.Cells("QR3DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value.ToString
            Dim qr4 As Integer = row.Cells("QR4DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value.ToString
            Dim qr5 As Integer = row.Cells("QR5DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value.ToString


            If Not row.IsNewRow Then
                Dim rating As Double = CInt((qr1 + qr2 + qr3 + qr4 + qr5) / 5)
                row.Cells("QRDataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value = rating
            End If


        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO tblRecords(ID,ID_NO,NAME,TI1,Q1,QR1,TI2,Q2,QR2,TI3,Q3,QR3,TI4,Q4,QR4,TI5,Q5,QR5,QR) VALUES(@IDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@IDNODataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@NAMEDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@TI1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@Q1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@QR1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@TI2DataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@Q2DataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@QR2DataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@TI3DataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@Q3DataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@QR3DataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@TI4DataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@Q4DataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@QR4DataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@TI5DataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@Q5DataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@QR5DataGridViewTextBoxColumn,@QRDataGridViewTextBoxColumn)"

        Cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, Cnn)

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvRecords.Rows
            'ADD Parameters
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("IDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("IDNODataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("NAMEDataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("TI1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("Q1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("QR1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("TI2DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("Q2DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("QR2DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("TI3DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("Q3DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("QR3DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("TI4DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("Q4DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("QR4DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("TI5DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("Q5DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("QR5DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("QRDataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value)
        Next


        Try
            Cnn.Open()

            If Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Successfully saved.")
            End If
            Cnn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Cnn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        Me.Validate()

        Me.da.Update(Me.ds.Tables("tblRecords"))

        Me.ds.AcceptChanges()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through... what line is the culprit?

Comment: You're going about things in the wrong way. Create your data adapter first, with all the commands (`SelectCommand`, `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and, if you need it, `DeleteCommand`).  Call `Fill` to populate a `DataTable`. Bind that to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the grid. The user can add, edit and delete as they desired in the grid. When it comes time to save, call `EndEdit` on the `BindingSource` and `Update` on the data adapter.  Tat's it, that's all. No `ExecuteNonQuery`; no `AcceptChanges`. `Validate` is pointless if you have no validation code.

Comment: Also, **NEVER** use `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872) out for an example.  The fourth and fifth code examples show how to use a data adapter to retrieve, edit and save data.

Comment: Me.da.Update(Me.ds.Tables("tblRecords")) - This is the line where the yellow error is appearing.

Comment: How can I create my data adapter with all those commands? Can't you please give me a sample code? As well as binding it to the binding source?

Comment: Thank you so much @jmcilhinney. The code was helpful but it's not saving back to the database. The error was gone and it's updating only on my datagridview. Now I'm so lost.

Comment: Edit the question and provide the code that you are currently using so we can see if there are any likely issues. That said, I'll wager that it actually is working properly and you just looking either in the wrong database or in the right database at the wrong time.  It's a very common problem, especially with Access.  First things first, test the value returned when you call `Update`.  It is a number and if that number is not zero then the save is working.  In that case, read [this](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx) to learn how to manage local data files.